# Nested loop optimization in cython: is there a faster way to setup this code example?

Tags: python, c, performance, fortran, cython

As part of a large piece of code, I need to call the (simplified) function `example` (pasted below) multiple (hundreds of thousands of) times, with different arguments.  As such, I need this module to run quickly.

The main issue with the module seems to be the multiple nested loops.  However, I am not sure if there is actually unnecessary overhead associated with these loops (as written), or if the code is really as fast it can get.

In general, when dealing with multiple nested for loops in cython, are there loop optimization techniques that can be used to reduce overhead and speed up the code?  Do any of these techniques apply to the example code pasted below?

I am also compiling the cython with `extra_compile_args=["-ffast-math",'-O3']`, though this doesn't seem to make a huge difference.

If this code really can't get any faster in cython (which I hope is not the case), would there be any advantage to writing all or part of this module in C or Fortran?

```py
import numpy as np
import math
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

DTYPE = np.float
ctypedef np.float_t DTYPE_t

cdef extern from "math.h":
    double log(double x) nogil
    double exp(double x) nogil
    double pow(double x, double y) nogil


def example(double[::1] xbg_PSF_compressed, double[::1] theta, double[::1] f_ary, double[::1] df_rho_div_f_ary, double[::1] PS_dist_compressed, int[::1] data, double Sc = 1000.0):
    return example_int(xbg_PSF_compressed,theta, f_ary, df_rho_div_f_ary, PS_dist_compressed, data, Sc)

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
@cython.initializedcheck(False)
cdef double example_int(double[::1] xbg_PSF_compressed, double[::1] theta, double[::1] f_ary, double[::1] df_rho_div_f_ary, double[::1] PS_dist_compressed, int[::1] data, double Sc ):

    cdef int k_max = np.max(data) + 1

    cdef double A = np.float(theta[0])
    cdef double n1 = np.float(theta[1])
    cdef double n2 = np.float(theta[2])
    cdef double Sb = np.float(theta[3])

    cdef int npixROI = len(xbg_PSF_compressed)

    cdef double f2 = 0.0
    cdef double df_rho_div_f2 = 0.0


    cdef double[:,::1] x_m_ary = np.zeros((k_max + 1,npixROI), dtype=DTYPE)
    cdef double[::1] x_m_sum = np.zeros(npixROI, dtype=DTYPE)
    cdef double[:,::1] x_m_ary_f = np.zeros((k_max + 1, npixROI), dtype=DTYPE)
    cdef double[::1] x_m_sum_f = np.zeros(npixROI, dtype=DTYPE)

    cdef double[::1] g1_ary_f = np.zeros(k_max + 1, dtype=DTYPE)
    cdef double[::1] g2_ary_f = np.zeros(k_max + 1, dtype=DTYPE)

    cdef Py_ssize_t f_index, p, k, n


    #calculations for PS

    cdef int do_half = 0

    cdef double term1 = 0.0
    cdef double term2 = 0.0
    cdef double second_2_a = 0.0
    cdef double second_2_b = 0.0
    cdef double second_2_c = 0.0
    cdef double second_2_d = 0.0
    cdef double second_1_a = 0.0
    cdef double second_1_b = 0.0
    cdef double second_1_c = 0.0
    cdef double second_1_d = 0.0



    for f_index in range(len(f_ary)):
        f2 = f_ary[f_index]
        df_rho_div_f2 = df_rho_div_f_ary[f_index]
        g1_ary_f = np.random.random(k_max+1)
        g2_ary_f = np.random.random(k_max+1)
        term1 = (A * Sb * f2) \
                             * (1./(n1-1.) + 1./(1.-n2) - pow(Sb / Sc, n1-1.)/(n1-1.) \
                                - (pow(Sb * f2, n1-1.) * g1_ary_f[0] + pow(Sb * f2, n2-1.) * g2_ary_f[0]))
        second_1_a =  A  * pow(Sb * f2, n1)
        second_1_b = A * pow(Sb * f2, n2)

        for p in range(npixROI):
            x_m_sum_f[p] = term1 * PS_dist_compressed[p]
            x_m_sum[p] += df_rho_div_f2*x_m_sum_f[p]

            second_1_c = second_1_a * PS_dist_compressed[p]
            second_1_d = second_1_b * PS_dist_compressed[p]
            for k in range(data[p]+1):            
                x_m_ary_f[k,p] = second_1_c  * g1_ary_f[k] + second_1_d * g2_ary_f[k] 
                x_m_ary[k,p] += df_rho_div_f2*x_m_ary_f[k,p]

    cdef double[::1] nu_ary = np.zeros(k_max + 1, dtype=DTYPE)

    cdef double[::1] f0_ary = np.zeros(npixROI, dtype=DTYPE) 
    cdef double[::1] f1_ary = np.zeros(npixROI, dtype=DTYPE) 

    cdef double[:,::1] nu_mat = np.zeros((k_max+1, npixROI), dtype=DTYPE)


    cdef double ll = 0.

    for p in range(npixROI):
        f0_ary[p] = -(xbg_PSF_compressed[p] + x_m_sum[p])
        f1_ary[p] = (xbg_PSF_compressed[p] + x_m_ary[1,p])
        nu_mat[0,p] = exp(f0_ary[p])
        nu_mat[1,p] = nu_mat[0,p] * f1_ary[p]

        for k in range(2,data[p]+1):
            for n in range(0, k - 1):
                nu_mat[k,p] += (k-n)/ float(k) * x_m_ary[k-n,p] * nu_mat[n,p]
            nu_mat[k,p] += f1_ary[p] * nu_mat[k-1,p] / float(k)
        ll+=log( nu_mat[data[p],p])

    if math.isnan(ll) ==True or math.isinf(ll) ==True:
        ll = -10.1**10.

    return ll
```

For reference, when trying to run this code, example arguments are

```py
f_ary=np.array([ 0.05,  0.15,  0.25 , 0.35 , 0.45  ,0.55 , 0.65 , 0.75,  0.85 , 0.95])
df_rho_div_f_ary = np.array([ 24.27277928,   2.83852471 ,  1.14224844 ,  0.61687863  , 0.39948536,
   0.30138642 ,  0.24715899 ,  0.22077999 ,  0.21594814 ,  0.19035121])
theta=[.002, 3.01,0.01, 10.013]
n_p=1000
data= np.random.randint(1,400,n_p).astype(dtype='int32')
k_max=int(np.max(data))+1
xbg_PSF_compressed= np.ones(n_p)*20 
PS_dist_compressed= np.ones(n_p)
```

and the example may then be called as `example(k_max,xbg_PSF_compressed,theta,f_ary,df_rho_div_f_ary, PS_dist_compressed)`.  For timing, I find that this example evaluates in ~`10 loops, best of 3: 147 ms per loop`.  Since the full code takes hours to run, any decrease in this run time would make a big overall difference in performance.

Comment: Maybe better put it on code review? What do you need x_m_sum_f for? I don't see it being used later on, so you could spare this array and just use a scalar or simply a longer formula in the assignment below it. Same for x_m_ary_f, I guess.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Calling `cython -a` on your code shows that almost all relevant part run in pure C, so there's not much to gain here.

Still, you're overusing arrays, where a scalar could be enough. or You're using matrices when a 1D array would be enough. Doing this optimization removes a lot of memory accesses, as showcased here:

```
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
@cython.initializedcheck(False)
cdef double example_int(double[::1] xbg_PSF_compressed, double[::1] theta, double[::1] f_ary, double[::1] df_rho_div_f_ary, double[::1] PS_dist_compressed, int[::1] data, double Sc ):

    cdef int k_max = np.max(data) + 1

    cdef double A = np.float(theta[0])
    cdef double n1 = np.float(theta[1])
    cdef double n2 = np.float(theta[2])
    cdef double Sb = np.float(theta[3])

    cdef int npixROI = len(xbg_PSF_compressed)

    cdef double f2 = 0.0
    cdef double df_rho_div_f2 = 0.0


    cdef double[:,::1] x_m_ary = np.zeros((k_max + 1,npixROI), dtype=DTYPE)
    cdef double[::1] x_m_sum = np.zeros(npixROI, dtype=DTYPE)
    cdef double x_m_ary_f
    cdef double x_m_sum_f

    cdef double[::1] g1_ary_f = np.zeros(k_max + 1, dtype=DTYPE)
    cdef double[::1] g2_ary_f = np.zeros(k_max + 1, dtype=DTYPE)

    cdef Py_ssize_t f_index, p, k, n


    #calculations for PS

    cdef int do_half = 0

    cdef double term1 = 0.0
    cdef double term2 = 0.0
    cdef double second_2_a = 0.0
    cdef double second_2_b = 0.0
    cdef double second_2_c = 0.0
    cdef double second_2_d = 0.0
    cdef double second_1_a = 0.0
    cdef double second_1_b = 0.0
    cdef double second_1_c = 0.0
    cdef double second_1_d = 0.0



    for f_index in range(len(f_ary)):
        f2 = f_ary[f_index]
        df_rho_div_f2 = df_rho_div_f_ary[f_index]
        g1_ary_f = np.random.random(k_max+1)
        g2_ary_f = np.random.random(k_max+1)
        term1 = (A * Sb * f2) \
                             * (1./(n1-1.) + 1./(1.-n2) - pow(Sb / Sc, n1-1.)/(n1-1.) \
                                - (pow(Sb * f2, n1-1.) * g1_ary_f[0] + pow(Sb * f2, n2-1.) * g2_ary_f[0]))
        second_1_a =  A  * pow(Sb * f2, n1)
        second_1_b = A * pow(Sb * f2, n2)

        for p in range(npixROI):
            x_m_sum_f = term1 * PS_dist_compressed[p]
            x_m_sum[p] += df_rho_div_f2*x_m_sum_f

            second_1_c = second_1_a * PS_dist_compressed[p]
            second_1_d = second_1_b * PS_dist_compressed[p]
            for k in range(data[p]+1):
                x_m_ary_f = second_1_c  * g1_ary_f[k] + second_1_d * g2_ary_f[k] 
                x_m_ary[k,p] += df_rho_div_f2*x_m_ary_f

    cdef double[::1] nu_ary = np.zeros(k_max + 1, dtype=DTYPE)

    cdef double f0_ary
    cdef double f1_ary

    cdef double[:] nu_mat = np.zeros((k_max+1), dtype=DTYPE)


    cdef double ll = 0.

    for p in range(npixROI):
        f0_ary = -(xbg_PSF_compressed[p] + x_m_sum[p])
        f1_ary = (xbg_PSF_compressed[p] + x_m_ary[1,p])
        nu_mat[0] = exp(f0_ary)
        nu_mat[1] = nu_mat[0] * f1_ary

        for k in range(2,data[p]+1):
            for n in range(0, k - 1):
                nu_mat[k] += (k-n)/ float(k) * x_m_ary[k-n,p] * nu_mat[n]
            nu_mat[k] += f1_ary * nu_mat[k-1] / float(k)
        ll+=log( nu_mat[data[p]])

    if math.isnan(ll) or math.isinf(ll):
        ll = -10.1**10.

    return ll
```

Running your benchmark on this version yields:

```
>>> %timeit example(xbg_PSF_compressed, theta, f_ary, df_rho_div_f_ary, PS_dist_compressed, data)
10 loops, best of 3: 74.1 ms per loop
```

When the original code was running much slower:

```
>>> %timeit example(xbg_PSF_compressed, theta, f_ary, df_rho_div_f_ary, PS_dist_compressed, data)
1 loops, best of 3: 146 ms per loop
```